# Java method for rolling dice returns 'doubles' every time

Tags: java, dice, seeding

I am creating a game where a user has to roll two dice and do certain things according to what is rolled. I have one method for rolling the dice, which I call twice to stimulate rolling two dice.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class test {

    public static int dice() {
        Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return generator.nextInt(6) +1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int roll1 = dice();
        int roll2 = dice();
        System.out.println(roll1);
        System.out.println(roll2);
    }
}
```

Consistently, the same number is returned for both rolls, even though they are being called separately.

Note: I was seeding the Random generator with the current time to avoid this.

Any help is much appreciated, I am new to Java!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That happens because you are creating a new `Random` object every time in the `dice()` method. When you call the method quickly multiple times (within the same millisecond), the `Random` objects will have the same seed, which is based on the current system time, and will produce the same random number.

Solution: Don't create a new `Random` object every time. Create it once, save it as a member variable, and reuse it.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class test {

    private static final Random generator = new Random();

    public static int dice() {
        return generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int roll1 = dice();
        int roll2 = dice();
        System.out.println(roll1);
        System.out.println(roll2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that works!